# Java project. Problem with JspWriter

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I got some old JSP web project at work that I am trying to import into eclipse. My experience with java and eclipse is far from great.

In one of the jsp files I am having error:
**The import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter cannot be resolved**

The code:

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory,
             org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement,
             org.apache.axiom.om.OMFactory,
             org.apache.axiom.om.OMNamespace,
             org.apache.axis2.AxisFault,
             org.apache.axis2.Constants,
             org.apache.axis2.addressing.EndpointReference,
             org.apache.axis2.client.Options,
             org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient,
             org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext,
             org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory,
             javax.servlet.ServletContext,
             javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,
             javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,
             javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter,                   <- Problem is HERE
             javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser,
             javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory"
     session="false" %>
```

And, of course, on any other place where I have reference to JspWriter I get same error.

I looked at Java Build Path and I have following:
1) servlet-api.jar - C:\Program Files...
2) Ear Libraries
3) JRE System Library (jdk1.6.0_25)
4) Web App Libraries

I used to have one item for Apache Tomcat 6.0 library which was unbound so I removed it. I tried to add it but couldn't. When I click Add Library > Server Runtime I get new window says: "Select a runtime to add to the classpath", but there is nothing to select.

I have installed: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Apache Tomcat installed (6.0), latest version of Ant and Windows 7 64bit.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> *The import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter cannot be resolved*

In case of Tomcat, it's part of `jsp-api.jar` file. However, do **not** manually add this file to the buildpath like as you did for `servlet-api.jar`, that would not be the right way! It would make your webapp *unportable* to other target runtimes (read: servletcontainers). I.e. your webapp would be compatible with Tomcat 6.0 only, but not with other container makes/versions like Tomcat 7, Glassfish, JBoss AS, etc.

---

> *I looked at Java Build Path and I have following:*
>
> *1) servlet-api.jar - C:\Program Files...*

Remove this one. It'll only collide with any target runtime which you're going to configure soon.

---

> *I used to have one item for Apache Tomcat 6.0 library which was unbound so I removed it. I tried to add it but couldn't. When I click Add Library > Server Runtime I get new window says: "Select a runtime to add to the classpath", but there is nothing to select.*

Go to *Servers* view in Eclipse. Rightclick it and choose *New*. Pick the appropriate servletcontainer make and version and walk through the wizard. Now you've a target runtime in Eclipse.

Then, in the project's properties, go to *Targeted Runtimes* and select the server in there. Nothing else needs to be done. Eclipse will take care of the remaining magic.

#### See also:

- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

Comment: Wow... Thanks to all of you. I accepted this one as correct answer cause novice like me could follow these directions :-).

Answer (score 3):

`javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter` will not present in `servlet-api.jar` of your Tomcat distribution. Rather, it is usually present in the `jsp-api.jar` file.

You should rebind the Apache Tomcat 6 Server Runtime, back into your project's classpath, so that all the JARs provided by Tomcat 6 are made available once again. An unbound Tomcat 6 Server Runtime serves no purpose other than to inform you that you've copied an Eclipse project whose classpath entries were or might have been valid in the original Eclipse workspace.

To reintroduce the Apache Tomcat 6 Server into your project's classpath, first define the Server Runtime in Eclipse, using your existing Tomcat 6 installation. Later, add the Server Runtime as a library in your project's build path.

Answer (score 0):

As the error is only with "javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter" i would have first gone and checked wether this class actually exists in the jar you have put in the project classpath. Also it is not a bad idea to create a new dynamic web project in Eclipse Java EE with required facets and just import the source files.