# How to include js and CSS in JSP with spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to include js and css files in my jsp, but I'm not able to do so. I'm new to the concept of spring MVC. For a long time, I've been working on this same topic.
My index Page is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/LoginPageScrip.js">

</script>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url("LoginPageBackgroundImage.jpg");
}
</style>
</head>
<body >
    <h6>Please login in google Chrome</h6>
    <h1 align="center">Welcome to my Twitter Clone</h1>
    <div class="m" style="margin-left: 401px;   margin-top: 70px;">
        <form method="post" action="LoginForExistingUser" onsubmit="return Validate(this);">
        <fieldset>
                <legend align="center">Login</legend>
                    <div class="a">
                        <div class="l">User Name</div>
                        <div class="r">
                            <INPUT type="text" name="userName">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="a">
                        <div class="l">Password</div>
                        <div class="r">
                            <INPUT type="password" name="password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="a">
                        <div class="r">
                            <INPUT class="button" type="submit" name="submit"
                                value="Login">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <i align="center" style="margin-left: 183px;">New User?  <a href="signup.html"><u>Signup</u></a></i>
            </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

And my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml is like this.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.csc.student" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>
        <!--<bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />-->   
        <!-- <bean name="/welcome.html" class ="csc.csc.helloController.HelloController" /> -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name ="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My controller is like this.

```
package com.csc.student;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    @Controller
    public class StudentInfoController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "/indexPage.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView getAdmissionFrom() {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("indexPage");
            return model;
        }
    }
```

Can some one help me in this? I'm struggling very hard but I'm not getting any solution. I have kept my js and css file in WEB-INF folder.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First you need to declare your resources in dispatcher-servlet file like this :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/folder/" />
```

Any request with url mapping /resources/** will directly look for  /resources/folder/.

Now in jsp file you need to include your css file like this :

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

Similarly you can include js files.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Could you please explain the benefit of using this approach like <mvc:resources> etc. Why Spring chosen this way rather than traditional access under webapps folder. Providing a link also welcome.

Answer (score 21):

Put your `style.css` directly into the `webapp/css` folder, not into the `WEB-INF` folder.

Then add the following code into your `spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
```

and then add following code into your jsp page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 5):

In a situation where you are using just spring and not spring mvc, take the following approach.

Place the following in servlet dispatcher

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />               
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/assets/css/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/WEB-INF/assets/js/"/>
```

As you will notice /css for stylesheet location, doesn't have to be in /resources folder if you don't have the folder structure required for spring mvc as is the case with a spring application.Same applies to javascript files, fonts if you need them etc.

You can then access the resources as you need them like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vendor/swiper.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

I am sure someone will find this useful as most examples are with spring mvc

Answer (score 3):

You cant directly access anything under the `WEB-INF` foldere. When browsers request your CSS file, they can not see inside the WEB-INF folder.

Try putting your files `css/css` folder under `WebContent`.

And add the following in dispatcher servlet to grant access ,

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
```

similarly for your js files . A [Nice example here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/) on this

Comment: It is not working. I have tried http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/ also but still same output.

Comment: You could check out the path intercepted in the browser console

Answer (score 2):

Put your css/js files in folder `src/main/webapp/resources`. Don't put them in `WEB-INF` or `src/main/resources`.

Then add this line to spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Include css/js files in jsp pages

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

Don't forget to declare taglib in your jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need declare resources in dispatcher servelet file.below is two declarations

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the folder containing css and js files into "webapp/resources".
If you've put them in "src/main/java", you must change it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you using java-based annotation you can do this:

```
 @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }
```

Where static folder

```
src  
│
└───main
    └───java
    └───resources
    └───webapp
        └───static
            └───css
            └───....
```

Answer (score 0):

**solution for anyone who want to store js and css files in src/main/resources folder**:
[project structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m6qV.png)

First, declare your resources in spring-mvc-config.xml file like this :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"/>
```

Then just use this to access the resource files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/css/style.css"/>">
<script src="<c:url value="/js/script.js"/>"></script>
```