# I can not include javaScript and css to my JSP page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I can not include javaScript and css fiels to my JSP page. I tried [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276603/how-to-include-js-and-css-in-jsp-with-spring-mvc) but not helped.

My JSP:

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../resources/js/my.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../resources/css/menu.css" />
...
```

and mapping:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources" cache-period="31556926"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and ctructure:

```
WEB-INF
 -pages
   -my.jsp
 -resources
   -js
     -my.js
   -css
     -menu.css
 -mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
 -web.xml
```

new structure not helped

webapp
   -resources
       -js
         -my.js
        -css
          -menu.css
     -WEB-INF
         -pages
            -my.jsp
         -mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
         -web.xml

What i do wrong?

Comment: Can you access http://yourhost/resources/js/my.js?

Comment: heck! it works in Internet explorer but does not work in chrome!

Comment: Do you disable cache?

Comment: I chek javascript in settings and it checled

Comment: can you paste your rea yourhost/resources/js/my.js

Answer (score 1):

Move your resources folder outside your WEB-INF and make your like below.

```
<script src="/resources/js/my.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/menu.css" />
```

You can't refer to the resources in your WEB-INF folder by relative path, you have mentioned.

Comment: Its the right answer. Did you move the resources folder, disabled caches, etc?

Comment: Yes i move "resource" folder

Comment: i add new structure in my quation

Comment: Looking at your above comment as it works on your  
"Can you access yourhost/resources/js/my.js?" , with having the resources moved out of your WEB-INF folder. Make sure you do a ctrl+f5 on your browser to fetch the recent change on the jsp page. Hoping your don't have any other sort of caching installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/my.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/menu.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your structure should be:

```
webapp
  -WEB-INF
    -mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
    -web.xml
    -pages
      -my.jsp
  -resources
    -js
     -my.js
    -css
     -menu.css
```

so that the static resources are not under WEB-INF. The `<mvc:resources>` tag tells spring not to serve these URLs at all, leave them up to your servlet container (Tomcat etc) to serve. But Tomcat et al will not serve content directly from the WEB-INF directory.

EDIT

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"
               location="/"
               cache-period="31556926" />
```

Assuming your project uses the standard directory layout, put your Javascript under: `src/main/webapp/js/my.js` and then access them with the relative URL `/resources/js/my.js`. Hope that helps.

Comment: i create this structure  but it not helped

Answer (score 0):

Do you have taglibs available in your JSP?

If so consider something like:
`<script src="<c:url value="/js/my.js"/>"></script>`