# how to add twitter-bootsrap and jquery to Spring MVC project

Tags: java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

My first time I created from origin a web-app and I'm new on Spring MVC.
I created a Spring MVC project and works as well. Now I want to add twitter-bootsrrap and jquery to my project and use these. Bu I don't know ho can I do that?

I use Intellij Idea.

I've to download bootstrap and jquery files and add to project not from the link source.

I'm using Spring MVC 4. Because of that I don't use xml files for Spring configuration. I use anotations.

Could you help me please?

Comment: this question is duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276603/how-to-include-js-and-css-in-jsp-with-spring-mvc

Comment: actually it is not duplicated. I use Spring MVC 4 because of that I don't use xml files for Spring Configurations. I realise now I didn't explain this on my entry.

Comment: I just posted a reply   see this response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line in your class config  :

```
 @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
                    "/resources/");
        }
```

in src/main/webapp/  create folders resources and add css js to this folder .

in your page jsp apply  your css and js like  this using jstl  :

```
<%@taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"  prefix="c"%>

    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Have I to mark resource which under the webapp as resource directory? Because Intellij create a resource directory under the src and I created properties files at.

Comment: Ok well done. Thank you for your interest. I clicked on your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the downloaded files take a look at [Spring MVC – How to include JS or CSS files in a JSP page](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/)

If you use maven take a look at webjars.
Also search abit more here on stackoverflow. A lot of questions regarding this already...

[webjars-in-spring-mvc](https://www.jamesward.com/2012/04/30/webjars-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Firstly thank you for your interest. I use Intellij as a IDE and maven projectcreated resource package under the src folder. Have I to create a new resource folder under the webapp? Secondly I do not use xml files for Spring configurations I use anotation. So How I do this things on anotation?

Comment: Look at [link](http://www.webjars.org/documentation#springmvc).
Should be something like

`@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
  }

}` Im not sure how to properly format comments, sorry! :)