# Failed to load resource error while loading js file

Tags: java, jquery

It seems basic thing but I couldn't figure it out after tried so long.

[image]

This is how my project structure. 
Following paths I have tried in my index.jsp but not able to load.

```
1) <script src="./resources/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./resources/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

2) <script src="../../../resources/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../../resources/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

3) <script src="../../resources/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="../../resources/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Can you suggest me on this? Thanks All !!

Error:
[image]

Comment: Try this and see if it works <script src="../../js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: @HayesRoach no luck.

Comment: Ok, try to drag and drop the files into the JSP page, it should automatically show you the correct path.

Comment: @HayesRoach its shows src/main/webapp/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery.js. But still same error.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation points to post a comment.

try to load the resources by following the server root.

If you start your link with a "/" the directory search will start at the server root.

So try "/resources/js/....."

Comment: I think its simillar to ./resources/. No luck.
<script src="/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Whats the error you get? Open the browser console and see. (ctrl + shift + I). Is it a not found (404) error?

Comment: You dont have jquery.js inside that folder!

Comment: Also "./" is not the same as "/". 

"./" is the folder of the current file.

Comment: Sorry for that. While try and error it got removed. But still other file not able to load. ie. ui.js

Comment: What do you see in the browser console?

Comment: Added screen shot in question description.

Comment: Try this link https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202666/discussion-between-h-udara-and-sachin-j).

Comment: yes Bro its working after adding jstl tags.Thank you so much. Can u add this link in answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276603/how-to-include-js-and-css-in-jsp-with-spring-mvc

Comment: Happy to help! Although no need to mark my answer as the "accepted". My original answer wouldn 't help. Credit the original author. Good luck